# Error in ChangeDetector Ref in Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-services

I have a similar error like other people. But I really can solve it. The error is ERROR `Error: ViewDestroyedError: Attempt to use a destroyed view: detectChanges.` I already view similar questions from others but I can see no good answer for my app. I want to detect changes like if there's new data for 5 seconds. I want it to appear to my browser. SO I've used changed Detector ref but it gives errors.

```
    export class UsersListComponent implements OnInit {
    closeResult: string;
    users: any;
    subscription: Subscription;
  modalRef: NgbModalRef;
  intervalHolder: any;
  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal, 
              private usersService: UsersService,
              private router: Router,
              private ref: ChangeDetectorRef
              ) { 

    ref.detach();
    setInterval(() => {
   if ( this.ref !== null &&
        this.ref !== undefined &&
        ! (this.ref as ViewRef).destroyed) {
            this.ref.detectChanges();
   }
}, 5000);


  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getAllUsers();
  }

  getAllUsers() {
      this.subscription = this.usersService.getAll()
        .subscribe(
          (data:any) => {
            this.users = data.users;
            console.log(data);
          },
          error => {
           alert("Error");
          });
  }

  onCreateUser(form: NgForm){
    const name = form.value.name;
    const email = form.value.email;
    const password = form.value.password;
    console.log(name);
    this.usersService.addUser(name, email, password)
      .subscribe(
          data => {
            alert("User Created");
            console.log(data);
            this.modalRef.close();
            this.usersService.clearCache();
            this.getAllUsers();
          },
          error => {
            alert("Error Adding");
            console.log(error);
          });
  }

 ngOnDestroy() {
    clearInterval(this.intervalHolder);
    this.subscription.unsubscribe()
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remember that you must clear the `setInterval` too on `ngOnDestroy`.

```
export class UsersListComponent implements OnInit {
    closeResult: string;
    users: any;
    subscription: Subscription;
  modalRef: NgbModalRef;

  intervalHolder: any;

  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal, 
              private usersService: UsersService,
              private router: Router,
              private ref: ChangeDetectorRef
              ) { 

    ref.detach();
    this.intervalHolder = setInterval(() => {
      this.ref.detectChanges(); // you don't need this detectChanges, you can just use the one in the getAllUsers and everything will work as expected
      this.getAllUsers();
    }, 5000);    

  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    clearInterval(this.intervalHolder);
  }

 getAllUsers() {
      this.subscription = this.usersService.getAll()
        .subscribe(
          (data:any) => {
            this.users = data.users;
            // This will help you with the initial load delay.
            this.ref.detectChanges();
            console.log(data);
          },
          error => {
           alert("Error");
          });
  }

}
```

**UPDATE**
Run `detectChanges` manually at `getAllUsers` to remove the initial delay.

Comment: It has no errors. But it loads the users list too long

Comment: @GraySingh it should load the users list immediately now.

Comment: Thanks for that. However when i open two tabs. I added a user in one tab, and it outputs immediately. However, the second tab, doesnt receive it. I should reload it to get the new user.

Comment: @GraySingh now I know what you want, to get that result you must call `getAllUsers` inside of the `setInterval`, I'll update my answer.

Comment: It still the same. I doesn't get new data in second tab when i added user on the first tab

Comment: Maybe you have to add something in the getAllUsers(). I have this this.usersService.clearCache();. Maybe if there's new changes, you use this clearCache() in the getAllUsers()? How can you do this?

Comment: I don't know what are you doing inside of the ´clearCache´ function, but it doesn't makes sense that you don't see the change in the other tab, if that s the case, try to put a `this.ref.reattach()` before the `this.ref.detectChanges()`, then detach again. Tell me if that works, do that inside of the `getAllUsers`.

Comment: Still i cannot get the new value from the second tab.  the console.log of getAllUsers of the second tab is not getting updated

Comment: Cardoza. I can only see the updated value in the second tab when i also add user in the second tab

Comment: @Gray did you add the `getAllUsers` to the `setInterval` block? Check the code in my answer if not.

Comment: Yes i did put it

Comment: It works now. However it says too many request when i open 2 to 3 tabs?

Comment: That are good news! Well an interval is always an overkill task, you can try to increast the interval time, but you should use a real-time engine like socket.io.

Answer (score 2):

I think the change detector is referenced to old view has been destroyed!
You can check to make sure your view is not destroyed before running the detectChanges.

```
setInterval(() => {
   if ( this.ref !== null &&
        this.ref !== undefined &&
        ! (this.ref as ViewRef).destroyed) {
            this.ref.detectChanges();
   }
}, 5000);
```

Hope this help!

Comment: It still loads the users list too long. I have added the cache service for getAll() above

Comment: Can you try to use `markForCheck()` instead of `detectChanges()` as here https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef#members?

Comment: I can't see users list anymore. But appears in the console.log

Comment: I don't think you should call `clearInterval` method in `ngOnDetroy()`.

Comment: Can you try to remove this 'ref.detach();' from constructor and make sure setInterval() is running?

Answer (score 0):

The issue clearly comes from **`detectChanges()`** because the changes were done and the method called during the destroy phase of the component.

To fix this, make your component to implements OnDestroy, then you need to cancel the changes that make this.ref.detectChanges() to be called.

```
export class UsersListComponent implements OnInit,OnDestroy {
  // ... your code

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.cdRef.detach(); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Ill maintain my code? And write this.cdref.detach() in ondestroy?

Comment: what do you mean

Comment: you dont have to remove anything add OnDestroy and call this.cdRef.detach

Comment: How about the setinterval? Will i remove it in the constructor?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156866/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-gray-singh).